# Object when passed as a parameter won't initialize in c# and fails

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass an object to a method in C# and I am observing that the formal parameter is not being referred to the actual parameter.

My method to which I am passing the object is

```
public DetailedTSClientInfo GetCommonServerDetails(string servername,DetailedTSClientInfo detailedTsClientInfo)
    {}
```

And I am calling the above method from the below function

```
public DetailedTSClientInfo GetAppserverDetails(TSClientAddress client)
    {
        var appServer = client.ClientIISserver.ToUpper();
        DetailedTSClientInfo detailedTsClientInfo = new DetailedTSClientInfo();
        detailedTsClientInfo.Name = appServer;
        detailedTsClientInfo = GetCommonServerDetails(appServer,detailedTsClientInfo);
```

I tried using `ref` and `out` for this object. However, everytime I get this error which says "**Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.**" and I am not able to get a work around for this.

(Attached an image which shows the error message)

Could anyone please help?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Object_Members]

[Edit-1]
Here is the exception which I am encountering.

[image: Exception]

Comment: What you are witnessing are debugger anomalies.  What is the _actual_ problem you are experiencing in terms of your program itself.

Comment: As the object is failing to initialize, my function fails to run and throws an exception with the same error message. Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "failing to initialize".   Also, as that error message "Unable to evaluate expression" is entirely a debugger message, that is not the error that is causing an actual real exception for you.

Comment: What exception do you get when you run it?

Comment: According to my understanding when an object is initialized, all its members are either null or initialized to their default values. So, since that's not happening in my case. I am assuming that the object is "failing to initialize". 

After reading your comment, I understand that I am wrong and this is a debugger error message. Can you suggest a work around for this?

Comment: What is this `DetailedTSClientInfo`, how is it declared? Edit-1: this is not _the exception_, you are simply getting the same message from the debugger about the exception itself. Try some VS cleanup: exit VS, delete .vs folder restart VS and rebuild the solution.

Comment: You appear to be hitting a `ThreadAbortException` and catching it (and any exception) to set `.Health` to "Offline".  You should do your best to provide a [minimum, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  You've only provided small snippets that you think is the problem whereas I suspect your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Umm.. Okay. I'll try that and let you know if it worked. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Also, are you compiling under the `Debug` configuration or `Release`?  The latter impedes debugging.

Comment: I am compiling under `Debug` configuration. 

Edit-1: 
@KirkWoll, My function fails at the first statement. I am trying to set a value to `detailedTsClientInfo.AppServer = servername` and my debugger gets to catch block.

Comment: @KalyanaSrinivas Check your exception settings (CTRL-ALT-E) and ensure "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" is fully checked and not a black square.  That will most likely lead you much closer to the actual cause of the exception.

Comment: @KirkWoll, Thanks you for the tip. I had checked CLR Exceptions and performed a re-run. It seems like my solution is not able to load System.pdb file whose dll is located at: `C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll`. The version number shown in the exception is `4.7.3190.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C`.

Comment: @KalyanaSrinivas but did it identify a line of your code closer to where the exception occurred?  Also is `DetailedTSClientInfo` your own type or pulled in via nuget or something?

Comment: It didn't identify the line of code or the place of error. It just says a System.NullReferenceException has caught. The `DetailedTSClientInfo` is my own class. I'll try asking my colleagues for assistance. Thank you so much for your time.

I am new to stackoverflow, Can you tell me how can I upvote comments?

Comment: Did you check if `client` is null or not?

Comment: I did. I was able to resolve this debugging anomaly by clearing VS cache and restarting the machine. I undo'ed all my pending changes and started development again. And mysteriously it did the magic! 

Thanks to @KirkWoll and everyone else who provided their suggestions. Happy Coding! :)